# Forma correcta de ocultar un <input> en HTML usando javascript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo mi codigo html posee dos input : pago y total
He implementado un script con el metodo keyup para que verifique que el pago sea mayor que el total y muestre el input de tipo submit.

El input de tipo submit se muestra solo si el pago es mayor que el total

Este es mi codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="x" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<input type="text" id="y" value="8">
<div id="boton"></div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = Parsefloat(document.getElementById('x'));
    var y = Parsefloat(document.getElementById('y'));
    if(x>=y){
    document.getElementById("boton").innerHTML="<input type="submit" id="boton">";

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Sin embargo no he conseguido la validación, agradeceré sus sugerencias

Comment: Prueba con `document.getElementById('x').value` Y el string de innerHtml debe llevar las comillas con escapes \"

Comment: document.getElementById("boton").innerHTML=\"<input type="submit" id="boton">"\; esto es correcto?

Comment: ”<input type=\"submit\" id=\"boton\">"

Comment: O también puedes '<input type="submit" id="boton">'

Comment: continua sin mostrarse el submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para mostrar u ocultar elementos los puedes hacer con la propiedad display none en css.

Puedes probar con algo asi

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <input type="text" id="x" onkeyup="myFunction()" /> <br>
  <input type="text" id="y" value="8" /> <br>
  <button type="submit" id="boton" style="display:none"> Algun texto </button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
       var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('x').value);
       var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById('y').value);

      if (x >= y) {
        document.getElementById("boton").style.display = "block";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("boton").style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Nota un par de cambios que hice, por ejemplo parseFloat, la primera es minúscula y la mayúscula es la F.
También la asignación de la propiedad value, en el parseFloat.

Mira acá el ejemplo funcionando https://plnkr.co/edit/ZJNmTFmihWzlYtLpROr0?p=preview